# Problems when installing spatie in laravel 6.20.29

Tags: php, laravel, installation

I got the next error when trying to install spatie in laravel 6.20.29

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

- paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99 requires php ^7 -> your php version (8.0.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
- laravel/framework v6.20.29 requires ramsey/uuid ^3.7 -> satisfiable by ramsey/uuid[3.9.3].
- ramsey/uuid 3.9.3 requires paragonie/random_compat ^1 | ^2 | 9.99.99 -> satisfiable by paragonie/random_compat[v9.99.99].
- laravel/framework is locked to version v6.20.29 and an update of this package was not requested.

Any suggestion? Please let me know.

Comment: What's unclear? One of the packages requires PHP 7, you have PHP 8. Since that package was patched [more than a year ago](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/commit/10e680e0e1f375980d7872dea75033c956b6804c) to support PHP 8, I'd suggest you need to run `composer update` first.

Answer (score 0):

Because you use older version of laravel, selected spatie package version is old too. This version of spatie is not compatible with php 8 and you should downgrade php or upgrade laravel version to solve this problem.